# Doubts about TensorFlow Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, regression

I was reading this [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/regression) when a doubt appeared. In the tutorial de dataset has 10 attributes (after the one-hot conversion), but when the model was created, the input layer has more neurons (64) than inputs (10).

Here's the code:

```
def build_model():
  model = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=[len(train_dataset.keys())]),
    layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(1)
  ])

  optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(0.001)

  model.compile(loss='mse',
                optimizer=optimizer,
                metrics=['mae', 'mse'])
  return model
```

I thought that the number of neurons should be equals to the number of entries. Can anyone explain this?
Thanks for your attention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 64 in your `Dense` layers specifies the number of neurons of the first and second **hidden layers**. The `input_shape` parameter specifies how `keras` will automatically handle the number of neurons in the **input layer**, so 10 in your case.

[image]

Comment: Just to be more clear, in this code, the input layer has 10 neurons, and the hiden layer has two layers with 64 neurons?

Comment: Yes, exactly that. Each hidden layer has 64 neurons.

Comment: Oh, now I got it. Thank you for your explanation, Nicolas.